# Do we need to generate token id everytime before call webservice

Tags: java, android, web-services, oauth, google-oauth

Hello I'm OAuth process to verify back end in android so for this I created a project at Google API Console, there I created client ID for web and android app.

This is I am doing because of to make the system more secure so that nobody hacker can hit my webservice anyhow, if anyone do then authentication server send the response (Invalid Token).

For this process in android, I have to generate the token. Google Play Service library has a method.

```
public static String getToken (Context context, String accountName, String scope)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#getToken(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

I have to generate this token ID every time before I'm calling any webservices in my app because afaik this token expires within a hour. This somewhat increased delay because first it get token ID from Google then I call my web service with token ID.

It looks like not a best approach. What you have a suggestion on this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach is to first check in your client code if the token has expired. If it's not, then don't generate a new token, just call the web service directly with the token you already have. And if it is expired, then first get a new token, then call the web service. This way you'll be making 2 remote calls only if your token is actually expired i.e. when you actually need to renew it.

To implement this strategy all you need to remember (in your code) is:
1) the date and time when you generated the token; 2) its duration.

Comment: how to know when that token will expire ? How do i get time after which it will expire ?

Comment: @Williams I think that should be in the docs of the token generation API. Or ... there should be another method in the token generation API giving you the duration (the validity time) of the token. At least, that's how such token-related APIs are usually designed.

Comment: Not sure if this is the same but check e.g.: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#expiration.